# Looking for a Tor email that does*n't* require JS to run

Tags: email, web-services

I'm looking for a Tor (dark web) email that does*n't* require JavaScript, and can receive and send emails from and to a "normal" email address. I also want end-to-end encryption. I don't need a huge amount of storage or top speed. Just something that works, and is safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a whack-a-mole game of privacy-respecting email providers (eg [Lavabit 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavabit#Suspension_and_gag_order)), but at the time of writing (2023), there's at least the following providers that offer webmail on an Onion Service that does not require Javascript:

1. Daniel Winzen: danielas3rtn54uwmofdo3x2bsdifr47huasnmbgqzfrec5ubupvtpid.onion/mail/
2. Cock.li: rurcblzhmdk22kttfkel2zduhyu3r6to7knyc7wiorzrx5gw4c3lftad.onion
3. Systemli: llqiiswupgezsco4ux47cco3bxsaihbss5c3piefv6bhvpgfofyk7kad.onion
4. Elude.in: eludemailxhnqzfmxehy3bk5guyhlxbunfyhkcksv4gvx6d3wcf6smad.onion/

#### Resources

The following websites maintain a list of privacy-conscious email providers.

1. [Privacy-Conscious Email Services](https://prxbx.com/email/) by prxbx.com
2. [Communications List](https://darknetlive.com/communication) by DarkNetLive
3. [Email Providers](https://old.reddit.com/r/onions/wiki/index/email) by /r/onions